# filter/identify dictionary keys that have matching values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Not sure if I need reduce, sorting, filtering or using the newer unique methods. I've even tried Equatable solutions.

I need to auto-identify keys that have matching values and take only those keys and put them into a new dictionary or array.

```
var userDB: [String:Any] = ["userID1":"gameIDa", "userID2":"gameIDa", "userID3":"gameIDc", "userID4":"gameIDd", "userID5":"gameIDe"]
```

As you can see only these two IDs have the same value of `gameIDa`. I need output of this result.

```
// [userID1, userID2]
```

Thanks

Comment: auto filter means?

Comment: To automatically filter.

Comment: why don't you try to create an extension of Dictionary for this? You will have to write your own method.

Comment: I still need the correct function/method even in the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init) to achieve this easily and then reduce it to a dictionary which contains only entries with multiple values.

```
var userDB: [String: String] = ["userID1":"gameIDa", "userID2":"gameIDb", "userID3":"gameIDc", "userID4":"gameIDa", "userID5":"gameIDe"]

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: userDB.keys) { userDB[$0] ?? "" }.reduce(into: [String:[String]](), { (result, element) in
    if element.value.count > 1 {
        result[element.key] = element.value
    }
})
```

> dict
>
> ["gameIDa": ["userID1", "userID4"]]

Comment: @tymac what if there is more than one?

Comment: No. what i meant is what if there is more than one value with which is repeated. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @tymac why do you need it in an array? And what would happen for multiple values with same keys?

Comment: You did not answer my second question. Also, how is it better than a dictionary? And how is a dictionary not letting you do that?

Comment: Oh sorry. Any efficient storage that allows for maximum json querying in the future. Like user age, location, skill level etc... I haven't accessed the API yet. I am just writing pseudo code for the logic. If you have a good idea please share it.

Comment: IMO dictionary is the best way you can store the required information.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input. For example I will take the user groups and put each group on the UI. Each group will have an identifier and the identifier will be the gameID.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in order to be able to compare values, the `Dictionary` `Value` type needs to be an `Equatable` one. Once this is fulfilled, you can easily filter the keys that hold the queried value:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func keysWithCommonValues() -> [Key] {
        // go over all keys and keep ones for which the dictionary has one another key with the same value
        return keys.filter { key in contains { $0.key != key && $0.value == self[key] } }
    }
}

// userDB is not inferred as [String:String]
var userDB = ["userID1":"gameIDa", "userID2":"gameIDa", "userID3":"gameIDc", "userID4":"gameIDd", "userID5":"gameIDe"]
print(userDB.keysWithCommonValues()) // ["userID1", "userID2"]
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case I need to input the value `"gameIDa"`. This is not automatic.

Comment: @tymac so you need to list all keys that have values appearing more than once in the dictionary, into a single array?

Comment: Yup. Just like Rakesh did. The print outputs to a dictionary but it would be nice to have ONLY the userIDs placed into a regular array. Other cool options would be great too like having independent out put of each gameID.

Comment: @tymac updated the answer, should follow the specs now :)