# reduce function is printing an empty dictionary [:]

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, reduce, codable

I have reduced my dictionary keys successfully in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320294/filter-identify-dictionary-keys-that-have-matching-values-and-group-them/54320417#54320417) as pseudo-code without a real json model. The goal which I accomplished in the previous question is to return **only the keys that have matching values**. So the output is a dictionary that looks something like this `["WoW": ["@jade", "@kalel"]`. Exactly what I needed. Of course there could be other matches and I'd like to return those as well.

Now that I have a proper json model, the reduce function is printing out an empty dictionary `[:]`. Is it the type in `.reduce(into: [String:[String]]()` that is causing the issue?

All the data is printing so the json and model structure must be correct.

json

```
[
{
    "id": "tokenID-tqkif48",
    "name": "@jade",
    "game": "WoW",
    "age": "18"
},
{
    "id": "tokenID-fvkif21",
    "name": "@kalel",
    "game": "WoW",
    "age": "20"
}
]
```

UserModel

```
public typealias Users = [UserModel]
public struct UserModel: Codable {

public let name: String
public let game: String
// etc...

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case game
    // etc...
```

Playground

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Users", withExtension: "json") else {
    fatalError()
}
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
    fatalError()
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
    for userModel in response {

        let userDict: [String:String] = [ userModel.name:userModel.game ]

        let reduction = Dictionary(grouping: userDict.keys) { userDict[$0] ?? "" }.reduce(into: [String:[String]](), { (result, element) in
            if element.value.count > 1 {
                result[element.key] = element.value
            }
        })
        // error catch etc
}
```

Comment: @tymac Something I can compile without having to spend time massaging json.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's all the code I had. There was nothing that needed massaging. Both Vadian and OOper answered within minutes with no additional code. The model and everything was in plain sight.

Comment: Lets put it another way. I want something I can copy into an empty Swift file, click compile, and see your issue. Right now your code does many things unrelated to your issue. It loads a `Users.json` file from the main bundel (which means a potential answerer needs to create a new xcode project, and create such a file), it decodes JSON (even though this same issue can be recreated using directly-initialized `UserModel` structs, without needing to parse JSON), etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve In particular: "Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem",  "Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem", "Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too complicated. You can group the array by `game` simply with

```
let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
let reduction = Dictionary(grouping: response, by: {$0.game}).mapValues{ usermodel in usermodel.map{ $0.name}}
```

Comment: please see my new code added to the bottom of my question. If that is correct I am still getting a `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error.

Comment: Remove the loop.

Comment: I updated the answer to map the values to their names. With the given JSON the error must not occur.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** I may be mistaking what you want to get. There's another code below and please check the results and choose one you want.

If you want to use `reduce(into:updateAccumulatingResult:)`, you can write something like this.

```
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
    let userArray: [(name: String, game: String)] = response.map {($0.name, $0.game)}

    let reduction = userArray.reduce(into: [String:[String]]()) {result, element in
        if !element.game.isEmpty {
            result[element.name, default: []].append(element.game)
        }
    }
    print(reduction)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you prefer an initializer of `Dictionary`, this may work:

```
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
    let userArray: [(name: String, games: [String])] = response.map {
        ($0.name, $0.game.isEmpty ? [] : [$0.game])
    }

    let reduction = Dictionary(userArray) {old, new in old + new}
    print(reduction)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Both output:

```
["@jade": ["WoW"], "@kalel": ["WoW"]]
```

Anyway, your way of combining loop, `Dictionary(grouping:)` and `reduce(into:)` in addition of `userDict.keys` is making things too complex than they should be.

---

**ADDITION** When you want to get a Dictionary with keys as games:

```
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
    let userArray: [(game: String, name: String)] = response.compactMap {
        $0.game.isEmpty ? nil : ($0.game, $0.name)
    }

    let reduction = userArray.reduce(into: [String:[String]]()) {result, element in
        result[element.game, default: []].append(element.name)
    }
    print(reduction)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or:

```
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode([UserModel].self, from: data)
    let userArray: [(game: String, names: [String])] = response.compactMap {
        $0.game.isEmpty ? nil : ($0.game, [$0.name])
    }

    let reduction = Dictionary(userArray) {old, new in old + new}
    print(reduction)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

```
["WoW": ["@jade", "@kalel"]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will upvote your answer. I marked @vadian 's  answer correct because he was first with the correct algo.